# How to release the evalutor memory when using Tensorflow train_and_evaluate API

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 1.12 version, and if I use `train_and_evaluate` API, the evaluator worker will increase the memory after each evaluating.

As the document says,

```
  Note that in current implementation `estimator.evaluate` will be called
  multiple times. This means that evaluation graph (including eval_input_fn)
  will be re-created for each `evaluate` call. `estimator.train` will be called
  only once.
```

If it possible to release the memory of evaluate worker ?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I had shuffle the eval data set.

Comment: If your issue resolved. Can you provide detail solution in the answer section for the benefit of community.Thanks!